# Chai response.body is always empty {}

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

No matter what my server actually returns, Chai always gives me this exception when I assert response.body:

> Uncaught AssertionError: expected {} to deeply equal 'test'

Even though the actual server response is 'test', not {}:
[image]

Here is my test:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const server = require('./test-server');
const should = chai.should();    
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('GET /test', () => {
  it('it should give test result', (done) => {
    chai.request(server)
        .get('/test')
        .end((err, res) => {
            console.log(err); // outputs null
            console.log(res); // outputs normal-looking response
            res.body.should.be.eql('test');
            done();
        });
  });
});
```

Here is my server (test-server.js):

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end('test');
});

module.exports = server;

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000);
console.log("Server running at http://localhost:8000/");
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: your response body returns object and you are equaling it with string

Comment: @p0k8_ what should I do then? How do I assert a reponse from the server? (which is string, not object)

Comment: not sure but `res.text.should.be.eql('test');` is what you might need

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Content-Type: `application/json`

`res.body` is populated depending on Content-Type header

test-server.js

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});

    var b = JSON.stringify({
      name: 'asad',
      class: 'paewe'
    });

    response.end(b);
});

module.exports = server;

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000);
console.log("Server running at http://localhost:8000/");
```

The `res.body` will contain the Parsed object

test.js

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const server = require('./test-server');
const should = chai.should();
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('GET /test', () => {
    it('it should give test result', (done) => {
        chai.request(server)
            .get('/test')
            .end((err, res) => {
                console.log(err); // outputs null
                console.log(res); // outputs normal-looking response
                console.log(res.body) // { name: 'asad', class: 'paewe' }

                var checkObj = {
                    name: 'asad',
                    class: 'paewe'
                }
                res.body.should.be.eql(checkObj); // passes test
                done();
            });
    });
});
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

### Content-Type: `text/plain`

If the Content-Type header is  `text/plain`, then the response body won't be parsed as anything, but `res.text` will contain the data as string

test-server.js

```
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.end('test');
});

module.exports = server;

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000);
console.log("Server running at http://localhost:8000/");
```

test.js

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const server = require('./test-server');
const should = chai.should();    
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('GET /test', () => {
  it('it should give test result', (done) => {
    chai.request(server)
        .get('/test')
        .end((err, res) => {
            console.log(err); // outputs null
            console.log(res); // outputs normal-looking response
            console.log(res.body) // {}
            res.text.should.be.eql('test'); // passes test
            done();
        });
  });
});
```

Some references

1. https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/990
2. https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/pull/10
3. https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/68

Comment: Thank you! It works.
Do you happen to know what to do when the Content-type is "applicaton/javascript"? How do I test it then?

Neither res.text nor res.body contain the server output

Comment: I asked a separate question about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43324004/chai-doesnt-recognize-content-type-application-javascript

Maybe you can answer it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When the server responds with 'Content-Type': 'text/xml' then body is also empty and res.text contains the xml as a string. - this is really not smart design.