# How to access Reponse text in TypeScript Chai?

Tags: typescript, chai

In the following `helloWorld.test.ts` I can't get access to `res.text` to test the HTML result:

```
import * as chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

import app from '../src/App';

chai.use(chaiHttp);
const expect = chai.expect;

describe('baseRoute', () => {

  it('should be html', async () => {
    const res = await chai.request(app).get('/');
    expect(res.type).to.eql('text/html');
  });

  it('should have the message in body', async () => {
    const res = await chai.request(app).get('/');
    //console.log("Result:", res);
    expect(res.text).to.eql('<html><head><title>Hey</title></head><body><h1>Hello world!</h1></body></html>');
  });

});
```

When I try to build my project in VSCode, I get a `Property 'text' does not exist on type 'Response'.` error, which is consistent with the autocompletion that only shows three properties for a `Response`: `body`, `status`, and `type`.

The `res.body` is always `{}` so, according to the answer to the following question, one should use `res.text` (in JavaScript): [Chai response.body is always empty {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320699/chai-response-body-is-always-empty)

How to get access in TypeScript to `res.text`?

Comment: Can you show the `response` object?

Comment: @ggorlen The `response` definitely has a `text` element. Anyway, I found the problem (see my new answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I had `@types/chai-http` installed (from an old tutorial), but https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/chai-http says it was deprecated. I'm assuming that in TypeScript it was a very limited API, as the version was 0.0.23 (or something).

`npm uninstall @types/chai-http` opened up the autocompletion for all the properties, including `.text`. This solved my problem.